# How to pipe stdout from os.Exec to file and to terminal?

Tags: go

How to pipe stdout for os.Exec to file but also to terminal?

I've try this:

```
go func() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(logFile)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Debugln(scanner.Text())
        writer.WriteString(scanner.Text())
    }
    writer.Flush()
}()
```

But `writer.WriteString(scanner.Text())` losts `\n` in file. How to got them back? Maybe there is some more elegant solution with pipes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [io.MultiWriter](https://godoc.org/io#MultiWriter) with arguments os.Stdout and the file. Set [Cmd.Stdout](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Stdout) to the multiwriter. Run the command.

```
 cmd := exec.Command(name, args...)
 cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, file)
 err := cmd.Run()
```

If you want to write line by line to log.Debugf and other files, then do the following:

```
go func() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, file))
    for scanner.Scan() {
        log.Debugln(scanner.Text())
        writer.Write(scanner.Bytes())
        writer.WriteByte('\n')  // add line separator
    }
    writer.Flush()
}()
```

This code assumes that the line separator in the input is \n.

Comment: And hoe to write to bufio.Scanner instead of os.Stdout?

Comment: @AntonMedvedev A Scanner is for reading, not for writing.  Please explain more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to write to log.Debugf as well, I was thinking of using scanner here.

Comment: ping @Cerise Limón